# How to force the debugger to skip over a method and anything it calls after stepping into Application.Run()?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

TL;DR - Is there a 'recursive' `[DebuggerStepThrough]`?

Is there an attribute I can use on a method so that when using *Debug > Break All* on an idle WinForms form and then stepping into `Application.Run()`, such that no breakpoint will be triggered on that method or anything it calls, when an event calls that method?

Here's some simple example code as an illustration of the problem¹:

```
static void Main() {
  Application.Run(new MyForm());  //I step (F11) into here to wait for events of interest
}

string GetSome { 
  get {                  //I don't want to wind up on a breakpoint here
    return "Some";       //as a result of OnActivated() being called!
  }                      //But I *DO* want to be able to step in here otherwise,
}                        //(e.g. as a result of OnClick() being called.²

[DebuggerStepThrough]    //Not interested in this event or anything it calls
protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e){  
  string come = GetSome;
}

protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e){  //But I *AM* interested in this event
  string come = GetSome;
}
```

**What I'm doing:** Once my WinForms form has fully initialized, got focus, and is now idle (no queued messages in message loop) *(marker 1)*, I pause the idle form with *Debug > Break All*. The form is in it's idle loop, so the debugger shows the topmost stack frame as *[External Code]*, with the previous stack frame being the `Application.Run()` line. I then hit F11 (Step Into). The form's message loop is resumed and the form re-activates and gets focus. *(marker 2)* The debugger will now pause as soon as a managed frame comes up at the top of the stack - e.g. once one of the events in the above code occurs. *(marker 3)* The form re-activating causes `OnActivated()` to get called.

**Desired behavior:**
I want the debugger to ignore `OnActivated()` and whatever else it may call. Once I click the resumed form, I want the debugger to pause on `OnClick()`, since the debugger is waiting for a managed frame to come up to the top of the stack.

**What actually happens:**
The debugger ignores `OnActivated()` (since it's marked as `[DebuggerStepThrough]`) - *good*, but pauses in the `GetSome` getter - *bad*. At this point:

- If I step through the `GetSome` getter, the form re-activates again, and I'm back at *marker 2* and I'm in a loop.
- If I step out (Shift+F11) of the `GetSome` getter, it has the same effect as pressing F5 - the execution of the program is completely resumed with the debugger no longer looking to pause at the next managed stack frame. I'm back at *marker 1*.

Interestingly, the debugger is actually ignoring the *"Debug > Options > Debugging > General > Step over properties and operators"* option at *marker 3*. If I step into (F11) `Application.Run()` manually when starting the form, with *"Step over properties and operators"* enabled, the debugger **does not** pause on the `GetSome` getter from `OnActivated()` being called!

---

¹ There are no explicit breakpoints set anywhere in the code. In the actual code I'm working on, I'm trying to get the debugger to ignore just a few particular redraw events (and whatever methods & accessors they call from other classes) while being able to use "Break All + F11" as a shortcut for stepping into whatever next event may occur (there are dozens of possibilities) without having to set an explicit breakpoint on each one.

² The reason I can't just mark all other methods that 'uninteresting' events call with the `[DebuggerStepThrough]` attribute as well is twofold: The few 'uninteresting' events I have call hundreds of other methods in all - that's a lot of refactoring and visible clutter to add; and since, of course, I would lose the ability to step through those methods when I actually need to when debugging.

Comment: Use F10 as already mentioned. Or set a breakpoint and use F5 to run. If setting a breakpoint isn't granular enough then set a condition on the breakpoint.

Comment: I've read your question 10 times and find your titles does not agree with your question body and neither with code comments.   You obviously want to step into GetSome but you "don't want to pause here"?????    Make your mind up

Comment: When i test this, it doesn't hit `return "Some"`,no matter what i do unless i break point it explicitly. so i'm confused

Comment: Completely reworded, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Please explain your downvotes! I don't know how I can word this problem any clearer :(

Comment: Yeah just ignore them, there are so many low quality questions that turn up every hour and the crusties in us just tend to downvote them on principle if it doesn't contain any effort. However, after the rewrite i think its a legitimate question.

Comment: You are asking for a feature that does not exist.  Some code is just plain hard to debug.  Yes, activation is one, painting is another.  Focusing event are less tricky thanks to Enter/Leave.  If neither a breakpoint on the *specific* code helps nor a few Debug.Print calls then you have to call in the help of the remote debugger.  Which lets you run your program on another machine, now the debugger can't interfere anymore.

Comment: Yeah, I was starting to think such a thing doesn't exist. Thank you for the remote debugger suggestion, that's a nice way to avoid some unwanted events from being called altogether